# Ransack with options tag and populating select list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

Im using Ransack pretty successfully at the moment with a regular old text_field for searches but i want an options tag with a select list of stuff that is in my database

My first question is how to properly use a options tag to filter through my list....

My second question is how to fill up those options with whats in my database

so i have

district name
 - sacramento
 - san diego 
 - something else
 - another district

heres the page with my table on it (_table_discounts.html.haml)

```
%tbody
  - @property_application.each do |pa|
  %tr
    %td.align_left= pa.project.token
    %td.align_center= pa.project.district.name
    %td.align_center
      = pa.property.address
      %br
      = pa.property.city
      = pa.property.state
      = pa.property.zipcode
    %td.align_center= pa.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
  %td.align_center= pa.submitter.try(:full_name)
  %td.align_center= pa.discount_code
```

heres my controller (discounts_controller.rb)

```
def show
  @search = PropertyApplication.search(params[:q])
  @property_application = @search.result
  discount_codes
end

def set_filter
  @search = PropertyApplication.search(params[:q])
  @property_application = @search.result(:distinct => true)
  @search.build_condition
  discount_codes
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :show }
  end
end
```

heres my filter (_filter.html.haml)

```
= search_form_for @search, 
  :url => set_filter_manager_reports_discounts_path, 
  :html => {:method => :post} do |f|

= f.condition_fields do |c|
  .field
    = c.attribute_fields do |a|
      = a.attribute_select
    = c.predicate_select
    = c.value_fields do |v|
      = v.text_field :value
 .actions= f.submit "Search"
```

i've got the conditional fields but thats not what i want......i just want someone to be able to select

district
 - sacramento

then everything with sacramento populates.....i feel like im getting close but I feel like I'm not understanding something.......

any guidance would be greatly appreciated

thank you

Comment: Any luck yet? (Asking due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114274/collection-select-list-with-ransack-gem)

Comment: yeah i used this in my view                                            = f.select :project_district_id_eq, District.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] } and it populate my select tag with what I needed....and filtered correctly!

Comment: Sweet, you should put what you did in detail in the answer and accept it

Comment: In response to the closing of this question. Searching from a set list of options (such as states/countries/timezones ect) is not outlandish for a web app. This is one of the major search gems on rails, and it's documentation does not mention how to implement this issue. Why is something regarding a logical implantation on a common  gem "too localized"?

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized

Comment: I just found this on google looking for how to do this -- it is definitely of interest. Gah.